# Prevent caching CSS for nopCommerce

Tags: html, css, asp.net, caching, nopcommerce

I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent caching CSS files on [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/), I've done this before by adding the date and something else to the end of how the CSS is called.

```
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Themes/CustomTheme/Content/css/site.css");
```

This is how the CSS is added in nop commerce, but I can remember how to ensure the CSS is not cached, and will load the file by the set date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you activate **CSS bundling and minification** in *General And Miscellaneous Settings/SEO Settings*, the "bundlekey" for the bundled css file will change every time you update a css file.
The browser will then redownload the css-bundle and get the updates.

When developing you can just "hard-refresh" with CTRL + R

Answer (score 0):

When you clear nopCommerce cache from admin panel, it will regenerate CSS and JS bundle names only if css file names are changes.

Thus, you can override logic which generate bundle name by throwing random characters in file name. But I found a quick solution (hack).
Create empty css file (version.css) and connect it in Head.cshtml. Each time when you create commit, change file name like this(version.css to versionv1.css). Now nopcommerce will regenerate bundle.
This will allow to keep commit history and prevents mess in commit history.

Tested in nopcommerce 4.2